# Efficient conversion from C array of struct to NumPy array with ctypes

Tags: python, c++, c, numpy, ctypes

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705208/cython-setup-py-compilation-error-in-dll-wrapping-tutorial-unresolved-external) where I was trying to use a C++ DLL with `Cython`, with a tutorial fit to my case that never worked, I decided to use `ctypes`. I now successfully call the function that interests me in my DLL using ctypes thanks to heavy SO browsing. I am now faced with the problem of using the results that is an array of struct in Python.

This C function is as follows:

```
void myfun(
                 double         a,
                 //...more double parameters
                 int            max_iter,
                 int *          nb_iter,
                 myStruct *     res_arr,
                 bool *         ok
                );
```

with `myStruct` defined as follows:

```
typedef struct  {
             double dat;

             int    k;
             int    m;
            // ... more int

             double b;
             double v;
             //...more double

            } myStruct;
```

I call this function through the following Python code:

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.CDLL('PATH_TO_DLL\\lib.dll')

myFunPy = getattr(lib,"?myFun@@YANNNNN_BUNCH_OF_Ns_NNNHPEAHPEAUmyStruct@@PEA_N@Z") # name found through dumpbin.exe (due to C++)

class myStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("k", ctypes.c_int),
                ("m", ctypes.c_int),
                #...more int parameters

                ("b", ctypes.c_double),
                ("v", ctypes.c_double)
                #...more double parameters
               ]

myFunPy.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double,
                   // ... more double parameters

                   ctypes.c_int,
                   ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int),
                   ctypes.POINTER(myStruct),
                   ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_bool)]

myFunPy.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

max_iter = 10000
a = ctypes.c_double(0.1)
// ... more double parameters definitions

nb_iter = ctypes.c_int(0) # value doesn't matter, it is initialized in myFun
ok = ctypes.c_bool(True)

res_arr = (myStruct * max_iter)()

myFunPy(a, ..., max_iter, ctypes.byref(nb_iter), res_arr, ctypes.byref(ok))
```

Now `myFun` modifies `res_arr` which is an array of struct as can be seen from the above code.
It is exactly

```
<__main__.myStruct_Array_10000 at 0x97966c8>)
```

after the code shown above, but I cannot understand how to convert it to a NumPy array for future use *efficiently*.

Sure, I could do for loops with stuff like `for field, _ in struct._fields_` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789372/python-can-we-convert-a-ctypes-structure-to-a-dictionary/), but that is not the point since I use the DLL to make my computations faster (I really saw the difference in the execution time). `res_arr` ranges from 200 kb to 1 Mb and has tens of thousands of lines and some dozens of columns, so I'm sure that there is a way to not go through all of it with loops, but I can't figure out how to do so nicely.

It seems that if it wasn't an array of struct, it would be easier. There are [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924482/how-to-return-an-object-from-c-that-contains-a-numpy-array-using-ctypes-interfac) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329663/access-np-array-in-ctypes-struct) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063080/casting-an-array-of-c-structs-to-a-numpy-array) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328205/numpy-structured-regular-array-from-ctypes-pointer-to-array-of-structs) (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913932/ctypes-fast-way-to-convert-a-return-pointer-to-an-array-or-python-list), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46043582/numpy-retriving-an-array-from-an-array-of-pointers), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47127575/copy-data-from-numpy-to-ctypes-quickly), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355524/getting-data-from-ctypes-array-into-numpy)) close to this subject but it's either about converting just a struct, just an array, or something close but never exactly like me, and I wasn't successful in adapting these solutions, so maybe there's a way to base an answer on that, but in any case I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have almost the same problem but in my case, I was using CUDA DLL so my compiler was `nvcc`. But I believe that this can also be done by the normal `g++` compiler. In any case, here are the steps I did in order to convert array of structs from my CPP file to useable Python list/array. I will not go through your code; instead, I will just give you example which can be be found here: https://github.com/jcbacong/python-cpp.git

But the important steps are summarized as follows:

1. Create a .cpp file with the necessary header file containing the `extern "C"` declaration for the function. In my .cpp file, I returned an array of struct instead of returning a `void`.
2. Create a .dll file using your compiler. Again, in my case, it was `nvcc`. The sample code I linked through my github account was compiled using `nvcc`.
3. In your .py file:

   3.1 Create a Python class with `ctypes.Structure` in order to replicate the struct definition in your .cpp/.h file.

   3.2 Initialize your input/output using `argtype/restype`. Since my .cpp function is returning an array of struct, the `restype` is given by `ctypes.Pointer(<your Python Class(ctypes.Structure)>)`.

   3.3 I converted all inputs to readable ctypes. After calling the function in my .py file, the resulting array of structs (`_results` in the example) can be converted to Python list using (`results = _results[:ARRAY_SIZE]`).

I hope this helps!!

Comment: It works indeed, thanks! I actually had rewritten my C code to work with an array of Double instead, and forget about Struct, since, in my case it could very easily be done (I just had Double and Int in there). And I also realized I had to ouptut the array if I wanted to work easily with it. This is the best solution though!